# ULN2803a relay connection

Tags: relay, connector, darlington

A motion sensor and a relay should be connected with an atmega328p. I soldered my circuit on a perfboard and have 5V power and ground rails on it.

Can I use the rail for the COM port of the ULN2803a or do I need to remove the VCC, jdVCC jumper on my [relay](https://www.ebay.de/itm/4-Kanal-Relais-5V-230V-Raspberry-Pi-Optokoppler-Modul-Channel-Relay-Arduino/252895985560?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649) and connect a separate power supply to it? And take connect the COM port to  that VCC?

It strikes me as a bit strange that  I would need that many power sources for such a simple project, including the socket for the lamp that should be controlled with the relay, I'd need 3 sockets for this project.

Also, am I under the correct impression, that the use of the ULN2803a inverts my logic? Without I switched the relay ON with LOW, now HIGH provides the ON state.

[image]

And on a side note, any suggestions on how to improve my schematics are welcome. I'm just starting out and I would image that my schematic probably isn't that well to read.

Regarding the diodes:

[image]

On the product pictures on my 8CH relay these are labeled D1-D8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ULN2003/2803 uses a Darlington output stage and this drops about a volt when activated so, if your 5 volt relays need a minimum voltage that is greater than 4 volts you might have problems. I'd consider using logic level MOSFETs directly driven from the IO pins. You will also need flyback diodes across the relays.

> Also, am I under the correct impression, that the use of the ULN2803a
>   inverts my logic?

If you connect your load (the relay) between output and Vcc (5 volts) then a logic 1 at the input will drive current through the relay coil.

> And on a side note, any suggestions on how to improve my schematics
>   are welcome. I'm just starting out and I would image that my schematic
>   probably isn't that well to read.

It's not bad - I've seen a lot worse. I'd consider using the GND/0 volt triangle symbol in several more places and removing the GND connections that string across your diagram. It just makes it easier to follow.

> Can I use the rail for the COM port

Yes you can but my preference would be to get rid of the 2803 and use MOSFETs and flyback diodes for reasons already mentioned.

Comment: "You will also need flyback diodes across the relays." in case I use MOSFETs right? The 2803 can be used as is because it already takes care of the flyback diodes? The relay also works with 3.3V inputs so I don't mind the voltage drops and I already have the 2803 at hand, so I'll stick to it then. If I still need extra diodes, 4001 will do?

Comment: 1N4001 would be fine.

Comment: But would I need them with 2803? And would I need to place them on the input or output site?

Comment: Across the relays unless the relays have them already incorporated. I don't read german so I could work out where the data sheet was.

Comment: Even if you did, there isn't one unfortunately. I found _a_ datasheet online and matched it with a picture I took of the relay. I would assume these are the diodes you mentioned? Or can you guess from the product pictures? My setup already fried an atmega (I assume from the lack of the ULN or MOSFETS) and I'd rather ask twice instead of frying another one.

Comment: @idkfa yes, they are the diodes exactly!